# groovy how to make 2nd groupBy and sum

Tags: groovy

I'm having trouble of making second `groupBy` and doing math: `total` and `difference`, the `total` is only sum() for positive number and the `diffenrence` is only sum() for negative number.

This is what I got:

```
[
    ["category":"Beer", "name":"Budweiser", "type":null, "price":50.00, "quantity":2],
    ["category":"Soft Drink", "name":"Pepsi", "type":null, "price":10.00, "quantity":5],
    ["category":"Soft Drink", "name":"Pepsi", "type":null, "price":10.00, "quantity":-5],
    ["category":"Soft Drink", "name":"Coke", "type":null, "price":10.00, "quantity":3],
    ["category":"Soft Drink", "name":"Pepsi", "type":null, "price":10.00, "quantity":7],
    ["category":"Alchool", "name":"Smir", "type":18, "price":5.00, "quantity":1],
    ["category":"Alchool", "name":"Smir", "type":18, "price":5.00, "quantity":-1],
    ["category":"Alchool", "name":"Bala", "type":20, "price":5.00, "quantity":5]
]
```

And this is what I'm trying to get:

```
[
    [Beer: [name: Budweiser, type: null, price: 50.00, total: 2, difference: 0] ],
    [SoftDrink: [name: Coke, type: null, price: 10.00, total: 3, difference: 0],
            [name: Pepsi, type: null, price: 10.00, total: 12, difference: 5] ],
    [Achool: [name:Smir, type:18, price: 5.00, total: 1, difference: 1],
            [name:Bala, type:20, price: 5.00, total: 5, difference: 0]]
]
```

My code that I'm trying:

```
products.groupBy { it.category }.collectEntries { k, v ->
        [k, v.collect{ c->
            [name: c.name, difference: c.quantity, total: v.quantity.sum() + Math.abs(c.quantity)]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: And what are you getting?

Comment: Why does `1` smir plus `-1` smir equal `quantity:1`

Comment: And why is there no total for Alchool in the expected output?

Comment: I wanted to separate between the positive and negative number

Comment: Forgot to update and change quantity to total results, but basically is giving me tons of repetitive information `[Pepsi:[total: 1]],[Pepsi:[total: 1]],[Pepsi:[total: 1]],[Pepsi:[total: 1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
products.groupBy { it.category }.collectEntries { category, product ->
  [(category): product.groupBy { it.name }.collect { name, p -> [
    name:name, 
    type: p[0].type, 
    price:p[0].price,
    total:p.quantity.sum { Math.max(0, it) },
    difference:p.quantity.sum { Math.max(0, -it)} 
  ]} ] 
 }​
```

NB: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5093590829105152

With a 'double groupBy' (it's not more simple, because you want to rewrite the nested data) :

```
products.groupBy({ it.category }, {it.name}).collectEntries { category, names ->
  [(category): names.collect { name, p -> [
    name:name, 
    type: p[0].type, 
    price:p[0].price,
    total:p.quantity.sum { Math.max(0, it) },
    difference:p.quantity.sum { Math.max(0, -it)}
  ] } ]
}
```

Comment: Till now I was doing `products.groupBy({ it.category }, {it.name}, {it.price}). ` and your answer worked! Thanks!

Comment: i have updated my answer with a double groupBy example